# Is there a noteworthy example of an internal congruence in a category without binary products?

Tags: category-theory

An internal relation in a category can be defined as a pair of jointly monic morphisms $r_1,r_2 : R \to A$ or equivalently as one monomorphism $r : R\to A\times A$, as long as the product $A\times A$ exists.

Here, I only want to consider internal congruences / internal equivalence relations (they satisfy additional properties corresponding to reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity).

I wonder how restrictive the assumption that binary powers exists is, that is:

> Is there a noteworthy example of an internal congruence in a category
>   without binary powers (in the sense of products)?

An explanation why this seems unlikely or probably not really important would be okay as well.

---

Apparently, it is fairly common to primarily use the second definition, even though it is less general. I believe this is because it makes the treatment of congruences much more convenient - this is the impression I got from reading a bit of "Categorical Foundations - Special Topics in Order, Topology, Algebra, and Sheaf Theory - Chapter IV", where things like the category of congruences or inverse images of congruences are considered. Initially I tried to rewrite the definitions, so that they require  as few limits as possible, but this quickly became rather tedious and the results where not as easily expressible in terms of things I already knew; so ultimately I stopped doing that.

Comment: Well, for instance, the category of $n$-dimensional manifolds for $n > 0$ will not have any finite products. But it has kernel pairs of local diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am not familiar with manifolds. Could you provide more insight (in the importance of this example)?